# Eclipse not recognizing import/build classpath

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

So I have a package that uses some junit imports. These ones in particular.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
```

Eclipse will only recognize these imports half the time. I'll run it a few times, then all of a sudden the imports aren't recognized. I close eclipse, open back up, and it works again for a few times.

I'm completely stumped as to what could possibly be the problem and obviously the solution.

Comment: Is ur build set to build automatically and you have to click clean all the time when that happens u don't need to restart eclipse.

Comment: I'm not sure how to check if my build is set to build automatically, how would I check on this?

Comment: Go to project option in eclipse and set it to to build automatically

Comment: So it was set to build automatically, but junit wasn't checked off for some reason. Seems to be working fine now that I've checked it. I'll update if it breaks down again. Thx

Answer (score 0):

If your project is in Maven , then first you can click in Maven and do Maven Project.or using mvn clean install through cmd.If it is not a maven project, then in Eclipse Click on Project and select Clean, and check in Build Path junit.jar is there . i prefer to  have lastest junit.jar